# TP-Link WR740N Statistics total bytes reset automatically

Tags: bandwidth

I'm trying to track bandwidth for each device connected to my network, but total bytes reset after 5 gigabyte and i can't track each device usage for more than this, is there's a way to change this ?

Comment: Ask the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the firmware, since many times there were large value limitations/bugs that caused the routers to even get stuck.

Also, make sure the device does not reset or the internet connection does not reset. Those may cause statistics to reload.

Comment: Firmware Version: 3.16.9 Build 150616 Rel.56751n, Hardware Version: WR740N/WR741ND v6 00000000.  I checked their website and it shows that this the last firmware for this hardware version.  Also, status shows that System Up Time is 6 days ago, so i think it's not about device reset

Comment: System uptime is power related. Do a log of your connection uptime. From command prompt, Ping 8.8.8.8 -t > Log.txt . Let it like that until after the counter reset. Check if internet failed at a point before.

Comment: I got some "Request timed out." in first 5 minutes. does this mean internet failure ? Also i think it really reset at 5 gigabytes specifically, because other IP statistics don't reset when the one with 5 gigabytes reset. here's an [image](http://imgur.com/a/TMVA8), i never saw more than 4919738488 total bytes for any IP

Comment: Yes, if normally you have ping response, it was a failure.

Comment: So is there's anything i can do or this related to my ISP ? Also i read about some firmware like [Gargoyle](https://www.gargoyle-router.com/) that are good for motoring, is this a good choice or should i just ignore it ?